# How to add x:Name to control created through xmlreader

Tags: c#, wpf

I want add x:Name to my xmlreader generated control

> This is code:

```
TextBox TextBox = new TextBox();
```

Method calling:

```
Create(TextBox.GetType(), "Rate");
```

Method:

```
public DataTemplate Create(Type type, string ShowColumn)
    {

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
        @"<DataTemplate 
    xmlns:controls=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007""> 
        <" + type.Name + @"  Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @" ,Mode=OneWay}""/> 
    </DataTemplate>");

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;


    }
```

> I tried to add(x:Name=""Rate"") to it

```
 public DataTemplate Create(Type type, string ShowColumn)
    {

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
        @"<DataTemplate 
    xmlns:controls=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007""> 
        <" + type.Name + @" x:Name=""Rate"" Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @" ,Mode=OneWay}""/> 
    </DataTemplate>");

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;


    }
```

> It shows this error(XmlException: 'x' is an undeclared prefix. Line 3, position 22.)

Comment: Your XAML is missing a declaration: `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`

Comment: Not working, can you illustrate with the above code where to add and how, that will be highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. `x:Name` is meant to generate a class member of that name in the code behind of the XAML declaration. Why don't you set the Name property?

Comment: Actually, i want to access the textbox by name which i created, through looping the rows of the datagrid. I fixed the first issue, now it is not accessible i.e, I cant find the textbox by Name